# Fetching modern sharepoint page comments and likes count using search api

Tags: search, search-results, spfx, search-schema

I can't seem to find the correct managed property for both modern Comments Count & Likes Count at all as all managed property within schema returned 0 counts.
[image]

[image]

I would like to avoid additional query again just to get each items likes/comments count when querying news posts using search api.

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/comments-likes/

Answer (score 0):

If it's returing 0, make sure you have set Crawl properly and everything goes fine...

Otherwise you can create your own Managed property and will it with the both crawled property, dont forget to set appropriate type and searchable, queryable, etc...

Comment: LikesCount are already mapped to LikesCount. And I can't seem to find the correct crawled property for modern Comments & Likes too. Any idea and suggestion for the correct crawled property?

Comment: so this is SharePoint Online? if you are mentoing modern likes?

Comment: Yes, SP Online and modern likes + comments counts